# Running a MySQL Query when Facebook Like Button is Clicked

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-like

I would like to add an entry into a MySQL table called `fblikes` every time a user likes a something on my site.  According to [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) page, you should be able to do this, and "edge.create" is "fired" when someone likes something.

What I want to do is run the MySQL query below when "edge.create" is "fired."

How do I do this?

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) 
{     
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO fblikes VALUES (NULL, '$submissionid', '$uid', NULL)");    
});
```

**EDIT:**  I am using the code below for the like button, and it appears to me to be including some sort of javascript library.

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
echo "<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
echo '</script>";
```

Comment: I was actually asking for the ajax part; if you use a javascript library like jQuery, it is very easy to do that. In plain javascript it´s possible, but more work.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing javascript and php. What you need to do is send an ajax request to the server in the callback of the `subscribe` function.

On the server side you need to have a php script that processes your sent-in variables and adds them to the database.

Are you using any kind of javascript library?

Answer (score 0):

FB.Event.subscribe <-- is javascript, so php won't work here.

What I would do is do a jquery post to a php page which does the mysql_query for you.

Put the jquery post inside the subscribe function.